# ¿Como puedo cambiar mis url en php con .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lo que normalmente se hace (uso laravel pero quiero tener el sistema de rutas con el *Php* común):

> www.mipagina.com/index.php?pagina=contacto

Como lo necesito:

> www.mipagina.com/contacto/

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Buenas tardes, te recomiendo usar un enrutador como: http://altorouter.com/
Es muy sencillo de configurar y podrás hacer todas las URL amigables muy fácilmente.

Como pone en la documentación solo tendrás que editar el .htaccess y poner.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

El tema que busca es "URLs amigables con htaccess".

Es crear un archivo .htaccess con las reglas de como interpretar las urls, no solamente funciona para urls, tambien para restringir, encabezar, etcetera.

Te dejo unos links que puede ayudarte a estudiar:

Configurar:  http://pressroom.hostalia.com/white-papers/configuracion-htaccess

URLs amigables: http://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/

Comment: La verdad, no es la respuesta, tampoco me sirve para este caso. Gracias de igual modo.

Answer (score 0):

Añade estas reglas al `.htaccess`:

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Donde `pagina`es el string que vas a recibir por la `URL`